# Dataflow appears to be stuck. can someone cancel the job?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Got an error message from dataflow. I tried to cancel it manually but didn't work. Error:

2017-12-13 (03:44:56) Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to t...: Workflow failed. Causes: The Dataflow appears to be stuck. Please reach out to the Dataflow team at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-dataflow.

Can someone help on this job? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please share the job id?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. Maybe this is the reason: When the default VPC network has been renamed or changed on a project, it is necessary to inform the new network name through WorkerOptions.network (--network on the CLI) when running a job remotely (DataflowRunner), or else the job gets stuck with no clue/clear log error message with what happened.